# Is instagrams Rest API "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}" not working / removed?

Tags: rest, instagram, instagram-api

I am using the Instagram Rest API for a simple application and I've hit a bumb.
The call `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}` works fine (I also have the `?accesstoken=XXXXX...` appended).

But the call for basic user information is not working. Not in the developer console and not in the browser when modifying my own URL.

Has the method been removed? Is it broken? If no one has an answer for that; How do you contact Instagram to report the broken link?

Comment: I was able to to report a developer issue by going to `Manage Clients` in the instagram developer domain and then select `Report Issue`

Comment: It is working. Please add to topic your full query with some `user-id` (for example: `200`) and without your `access_token` or `client_id`. Also add response. My example works fine: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/200/?client_id=CLIENT_ID`

Comment: Wow, it is working just fine. I did not realise. I was just looking for another functionality. I didn't want to enter an integer, I wanted to enter a string; the username: like the site uses: https://instagram.com/tyrabanks

Comment: You need use two endpoints for it: [Searching user](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_search) and  [Users](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users) if in `Searching` missing some information, that you need. I note that in some cases it won't work ("Unique Searching Algorithm") or user is `private`. Direct link works well, you may try to get information from it, just remember that sometimes syntax of response may changing.

Comment: That's true. I'll look out for the changing responses ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @CnapoB I managed to realise the call wasnt what I was looking for! And also he showed me the Instagram Endpoints doesn't show the easy way!

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

might as well be

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}?client_id=CLIENT_ID`

which means you don't have to have the user login to the application etc.

Thank you so much for this!

What I wanted to do was instead this: (example: `tyrabanks`)

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=tyrabanks&client_id=CLIENT_ID&count=1`